# How to display future date and today date in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-express

I have this and wish to display future date and today date how can it be done?

```
Date
-----------
10/08/2014
09/08/2014
11/08/2014
```

and I only wish to display

```
10/08/2014
11/08/2014
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I am using SQL EXPRESS for my Database

Answer (score 4):

Most versions of SQL have some way of getting the current date.  For instance:

```
where date >= cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date)
where date >= cast(getdate() as date)
where date >= date(now())
where date >= trunc(date)
```

The specific syntax you need depends on the database you are using.

EDIT:

The first or second versions should work with SQL Server Express.

Answer (score 0):

SQL will consider your date "11/08/2014" in mm/dd/yyyy format by default. You would need to rearrange the month before the date like "08/11/2014" before making the comparison. Below code will get you the required results:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),CAST(Time AS DATE),120)
FROM Table
WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),CAST(Time AS DATE),120)>=CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),GETDATE(),120)
```